# Cannot get widget's property in build function

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I have two statefulWidget: Parent and Child.

And I wanna pass params from parent to child in **initState()**.

```dart
// Parent.dart
class _ParentState extends State {
  Child _child = Child()

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState()
      _dealWithChild();
  }

  function _dealWithChild() {
      await SomeFunction()
      ...   
      _child.paths = '';
  }
}
```

And get the params in the child:

```dart
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  String? _paths;
  String? get paths => _paths;
  set paths(String? value) {
    _paths = value;
  }
}


class _ChildState extends State {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _imagePaths = [];
    //The widget.paths always null!
    if (widget.paths != null) {
      _imagePaths = widget.paths!.split(',');
    }
  }
}
```

But I cannot get the params in Child's build function. And if I **don't** call the **async  SomeFunction()** in Parent, it works fine.

The question is that I have to call the async function and I cannot add **async** keyword to **initState**.

So how can I solve thie correctly?

Comment: Take a look at Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/interactivity#the-parent-widget-manages-the-widgets-state

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using state management solutions like provider or block, that way you can set a state variable outside the widget tree & update it in any lifecycle method as and when needed, once you update the value of that path variable, the listener will get notified in the child ui & update it right away, below code might help,

```
flutter pub add provider
```

model.dart

```
class ModelState extends ChangeNotifier{
final List<String> imagePaths;

const ModelState({this.imagePaths = []}):super();

void updatePathsToList(String input){
imagePaths = input.split(",");
notifyListeners();
}

}
```

accessing functions of provider from parent function to input the path

```
initState((){
context.read<ModelProvider>().updatePathsToList(_path)
})
```

Using in UI (watching changes)

```
context.watch<ModelProvider>().imagePaths
```

The above approach should help, go through a basic provider video to understand how this works.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but failed with: ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ModelState> above this Child Widget

Comment: You will need to add provider scope around your material app & create the provider instance of it, something like shown below,
```
Provider(
  create: (_) => ModelState(),
  child: MaterialApp()
)
```

Comment: Also, please mark the tick for the solution if this works, & let me know if there are any difficulties.

Comment: Is it necessary to around the MaterialApp()? I just wanna use it in deeply widgets.

Comment: yes, it is, state management tools works that way, the state you define goes on top of the widget tree & that's the reason you can use it anywhere & everywhere throughout the app, also don't worry it's the most optimized approach & just rebuilds the region of ui where it's getting used & not the complete widget tree.
Also, there's a Multiprovider widger you can wrap around materialApp widget which allows you to initialize all the provider instances.